# Pie chart in monotouch

Tags: c#, ios, graphics, xamarin.ios, pie-chart

I would like to draw a clickable pie chart in monotouch c# how Could I do that. for example if I click on particular portion on the chart then it will show corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

There are (old) bindings for [CorePlot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot) available on [github](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings) that contains several types of [charts](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/PlotExamples), including pie charts.

Note that you'll likely have to update the bindings a bit for the latest MonoTouch releases and CorePlot library.

Comment: The binding and samples were updated for CorePlot 0.4 API. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

ShinobiControls Chart supports [MonoTouch and provides bindings](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2012/08/01/shinobicontrols-monotouch-bindings-%E2%80%93-the-full-story/). They supply pie charts that handle clicks and animate gracefully.

NOTE: I am associated with the ShinobiControls company.